# Delete from $http.defaults.transformRequest array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am adding a header to HTTP requests like this

```
$http.defaults.transformRequest.push(function (data, headersGetter) {
    headersGetter().authToken = "myAuthToken";
    return data;
});
```

How do I go about removing that header later? I realize I could do a `.pop()` but if for some reason I have `.push()`'d any more functions, I would not remove the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by naming the function

```
// Add header
$http.defaults.transformRequest.push(function addAuthToken(data, headersGetter) {
    headersGetter().authToken = "myAuthToken";
    return data;
});

// Remove header
$http.defaults.transformRequest = $http.defaults.transformRequest.filter(function (func) {
    return !(func.name == "addAuthToken");
});
```